# intent send pojo object in second activity, in second activity object get but object inner list return null

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, onactivityresult

i heve one pojo class name contact

i open new activity for edit it

using this

```
Intent iEditContact = new Intent(JsonParseActivity.this, EditContatctActivity.class);
            iEditContact.putExtra(Constant.intent_key_edit_contact, contact);
            startActivityForResult(iEditContact, Constant.edt_contect_request_code);
```

i received that contact using this

```
if (iContact != null && iContact.hasExtra(Constant.intent_key_edit_contact)) {
        contact = iContact.getParcelableExtra(Constant.intent_key_edit_contact);
```

after i updte its name and number and other details...i want send again that pojo to my main activity and refresh recyclerview

how to do this with help of OnActivityResult() for without create new activity again

and how to retrive that list again in my mainactivtiy

Answer (score 1):

> How to retrieve that List again in my mainactivtiy ?

Well , you can use a **BroadcastReceiver** to receive it back to the **1st Activity** , have a look..

In *1st Activity*

make a field variable of `broadcastReceiver`

```
 BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Contact contact;
        if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
           contact = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constant.intent_key_edit_contact);
    }
};
```

And in `onResume` register the receiver !!

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("receive_contact"));        
}
```

And in *2nd activity* after making `modification` to the `contact object`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("receive_contact");
 intent.putExtra(Constant.intent_key_edit_contact, contact);
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```